# Set column value if certain record exists in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How could I create a view for a table with subset of the table's records, all of the table's columns, plus additional "flag" column whose value is set to 'X' if the table contains certain type of record? For example, consider the following relations table `Relations`, where values for types stand for `H'-human, 'D'-dog`:

```
 id | type | relation | related
--------------------------------
 H1 |  H   | knows    | D2 
 H1 |  H   | owns     | D2 
 H2 |  H   | knows    | D1 
 H2 |  H   | owns     | D1
 H3 |  H   | knows    | D1
 H3 |  H   | knows    | D2
 H3 |  H   | treats   | D1
 H3 |  H   | treats   | D2
 D1 |  D   | bites    | H3
 D2 |  D   | bites    | H3
```

There may not be any particular order of records in this table.

I seek to create a view `Humans` which will contain all human-to-dog `knows` relations from `Relations` and  all of the `Relations`'s columns and additional column `isOwner` storing `'X'` if a human in a given relation owns someone:

```
 id | type | relation | related | isOwner
------------------------------------------
 H1 |  H   | knows    |    D2   |    X
 H2 |  H   | knows    |    D1   |    X
 H3 |  H   | knows    |    D1   |
```

but struggling quite a bit with this. Do you know of a way to do it, preferably in one `CREATE VIEW` call, or any way really?

Comment: @plalx, not at all. Thank you both of you @plalx and @1_CR for great  answers! I wish I could accept both, since the final version turned out to be their combination. About `owns VS related only`, what I wanted was `related = r.related`, but have to admit I did not state this properly in the question. Thank you guys again - you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW vHumanDogRelations
AS
SELECT
    id,
    type,
    relation,
    related,
    -- Consider using a bit 0/1 instead
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Relations
            WHERE 
                id = r.id
                AND related = r.related -- Owns someone or this related only?
                AND relation = 'owns'    
        ) THEN 'X'
        ELSE ''
    END AS isOwner
FROM Relations r
WHERE 
    relation = 'knows'
    AND type = 'H'
    AND related = 'D';
```

Comment: note that this marks `H3` as an Owner even when H3 is not in an "owns" relationship

Comment: @1_CR I fixed it now. What I initially understood did not made any sense, but I still thought that's what the OP wanted somehow ;)

Comment: note that `AND related = r.related` may be too constraining from the OP's perspective. To quote the OP, "storing 'X' if a human in a given relation owns someone"

Comment: @1_CR Perhaps, however it seems to make more sense the way I implemented it, but you are right so I added a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to put the following `select` into the view definition

```
select *, case when exists 
(select * from Relations where id = r.id and relation= 'owns') then 'X'
else '' end as isOwner 
from Relations r
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use PIVOT to achieve the desired result. I'll explain the method in details because the final query may appear confusing.

First, derive a subset from `Relation` where `type` is `H` ans `relation` either `knows` or `owns`, replacing the `owns` value with `X`:

```
SELECT
  id,
  type,
  relation = CASE relation WHEN 'owns' THEN 'X' ELSE relation END,
  related
FROM Relations
WHERE type = 'H'
  AND relation IN ('knows', 'owns')
```

Based on your example, you'll get this:

```
id  type  relation  related
--  ----  --------  -------
H1   H    knows     D2
H1   H    owns      D2
H2   H    knows     D1
H2   H    owns      D1
H3   H    knows     D1
H3   H    knows     D2
```

Next, apply this PIVOT clause to the result of the first query:

```
PIVOT (
  MAX(relation) FOR relation IN (knows, X)
) AS p
```

It will group rows with identical `id, type, related` values into a single row and split `relation` into two columns, `knows` and `X`:

```
id  type  related  knows  X
--  ----  -------  -----  ----
H1   H    D2       knows  X
H2   H    D1       knows  X
H3   H    D1       knows  NULL
H3   H    D2       knows  NULL
```

At this point you only need to rearrange the column set slightly for the output in the main SELECT clause, renaming `knows` to `relation` and `X` to `isOwner` along the way:

```
SELECT
  id,
  type,
  relation = knows,
  related,
  isOwner = X
...
```

Output:

```
id  type  relation  related  isOwner
--  ----  --------  -------  -------
H1   H    knows     D2       X
H2   H    knows     D1       X
H3   H    knows     D1       NULL
H3   H    knows     D2       NULL
```

NULLs, of course, can easily be substituted with empty strings, if that is necessary.

One final touch may be to add this additional filter to the main query:

```
WHERE knows IS NOT NULL
```

just in case there can be people that own dogs without actually knowing them (and you don't want those in the output).

So, the complete query would look like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  type,
  relation = knows,
  related,
  isOwner = X
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    type,
    relation = CASE relation WHEN 'owns' THEN 'X' ELSE relation END,
    related
  FROM Relations
  WHERE type = 'H'
    AND relation IN ('knows', 'owns')
) AS s
PIVOT (
  MAX(relation) FOR relation IN (knows, X)
) AS p
WHERE knows IS NOT NULL
;
```

A SQL Fiddle demo for this solution is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e373a/3).

Comment: +1 This is pretty cool; did not know about such a thing. Thank you.